# How do you find an odd hole in a graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Why is there no literature on finding odd holes in a general undirected graph? I found this paper that seems to enumerate ALL chordless cycles (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.1051v4.pdf) but apparently, I read somewhere else that finding odd holes in the graph is a more difficult problem (and possibly open?)

Why can't we pull out the odd holes from the cycles found above? Furthermore, is it possible to find just ONE odd hole in a graph efficiently?

Answer (score 4):

See the following JACM 2020 paper for the first-known polynomial-time algorithm, running in $O(n^9)$ time, for finding an odd hole in an $n$-vertex graph:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.00208

The following STOC 2020 paper reduces the running time to $O(n^8)$:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.07446

The above paper also reduces the running time of finding an even hole from $O(n^{11})$  to $O(n^9)$.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to find an even-hole in time $O(n^{11})$.

But strangely for finding an odd-hole, we don't know if there's a polynomial-time algorithm that does so.  And we don't know if it's NP-Hard.

This is based on the following reference : https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0358.

You can check the related work section.